# What PHP extensions are preferred? And what about Security preferences?

Tags: php

If you are to install PHP on IIS, what PHP extensions would be good to be installed along with the ones that come by default with PHP? Also, any security extensions/configurations preferred usually?

I am thinking Fast CGI, CURL and GD library are required ones. Any other suggestions?

I am installing it for a friend, and he asked me to install whatever extensions that he might use in his applications. He is planning to install applications such as Content Management System, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the phpinfo() dump of a major and good working shared web host. Almost any kind of CMS works fine on them and have good database and other library support. Look for extensions in this:

---

Here We Go............... PHP Version 5.2.9

```
System  Linux xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Wed Jun 23 11:16:22 EDT 2010 i686 
Build Date  Jul 19 2010 17:34:10 
Configure Command   './configure' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/' '--with-ttf' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/opt/xslt/' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' 
Server API  CGI 
Virtual Directory Support   disabled 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/lib 
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini 
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none) 
additional .ini files parsed    (none) 
PHP API     20041225 
PHP Extension   20060613 
Zend Extension  220060519 
Debug Build     no 
Thread Safety   disabled 
Zend Memory Manager     enabled 
IPv6 Support    enabled 
Registered PHP Streams  zip, php, file, data, dict, ftp, ftps, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp, compress.zlib 
Registered Stream Socket Transports     tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls 
Registered Stream Filters   string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, convert.iconv.*, zlib.* 

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.3.20, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2009, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.31, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH


PHP Credits
Configuration
PHP CoreDirective   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  On  On
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   symlink,exec,popen,proc_close,proc_open,system,dl,passthru,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd    symlink,exec,popen,proc_close,proc_open,system,dl,passthru,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd
display_errors  STDOUT  STDOUT
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   error_log   error_log
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 6135    6135
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php   .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    On  On
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
max_execution_time  60  60
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   12  12
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  On  On
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    On  On
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 30M 30M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
variables_order EGPCS   EGPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off Off


bcmathBCMath support    enabled 


calendarCalendar support    enabled 


cgiDirective    Local Value Master Value
cgi.check_shebang_line  1   1
cgi.fix_pathinfo    1   1
cgi.nph 0   0
cgi.rfc2616_headers 0   0


ctypectype functions    enabled 


curlcURL support    enabled 
cURL Information    libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5 


datedate/time support   enabled 
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2009.1 
Timezone Database   internal 
Default timezone    Asia/Calcutta 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value


domDOM/XML  enabled 
DOM/XML API Version     20031129 
libxml Version  2.7.6 
HTML Support    enabled 
XPath Support   enabled 
XPointer Support    enabled 
Schema Support  enabled 
RelaxNG Support     enabled 


exifEXIF Support    enabled 
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: exif.c,v 1.173.2.5.2.27 2008/12/31 11:17:37 sebastian Exp $ 
Supported EXIF Version  0220 
Supported filetypes     JPEG,TIFF 


filterInput Validation and Filtering    enabled 
Revision    $Revision: 1.52.2.45 $ 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value


ftpFTP support  enabled 


gdGD Support    enabled 
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible) 
FreeType Support    enabled 
FreeType Linkage    with freetype 
FreeType Version    2.2.1 
GIF Read Support    enabled 
GIF Create Support  enabled 
JPG Support     enabled 
PNG Support     enabled 
WBMP Support    enabled 
XPM Support     enabled 
XBM Support     enabled 


gettextGetText Support  enabled 


hashhash support    enabled 
Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru gost adler32 crc32 crc32b haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 


iconviconv support  enabled 
iconv implementation    glibc 
iconv library version   2.5 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1


imapIMAP c-Client Version   2007e 
SSL Support     enabled 
Kerberos Support    enabled 


jsonjson support    enabled 
json version    1.2.1 


libxmllibXML support    active 
libXML Version  2.7.6 
libXML streams  enabled 


mbstringMultibyte Support   enabled 
Multibyte string engine     libmbfl 
Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled 
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version     4.4.4 
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check     On 

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input pass    pass
mbstring.http_output    pass    pass
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value


mcryptmcrypt support    enabled
Version     2.5.8 
Api No  20021217 
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes 
Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value


mysqlMySQL Support  enabled
Active Persistent Links     0 
Active Links    0 
Client API version  5.0.91 
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external 
MYSQL_SOCKET    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/include/mysql 
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    no value    no value
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off


mysqliMysqlI Support    enabled
Client API library version  5.0.91 
Client API header version   5.0.91 
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off


opensslOpenSSL support  enabled 
OpenSSL Version     OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008 


pcrePCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled 
PCRE Library Version    8.02 2010-03-19 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    100000  100000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000


PDOPDO support  enabled
PDO drivers     sqlite, sqlite2, mysql 


pdo_mysqlPDO Driver for MySQL, client library version   5.0.91


pdo_sqlitePDO Driver for SQLite 3.x enabled
PECL Module version     (bundled) 1.0.1 $Id: pdo_sqlite.c,v 1.10.2.6.2.4 2008/12/31 11:17:42 sebastian Exp $ 
SQLite Library  3.3.7 


posixRevision   $Revision: 1.70.2.3.2.22 $ 


ReflectionReflection    enabled
Version     $Id: php_reflection.c,v 1.164.2.33.2.55 2008/12/31 11:17:42 sebastian Exp $ 


sessionSession Support  enabled 
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite 
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0


SimpleXMLSimplexml support  enabled
Revision    $Revision: 1.151.2.22.2.46 $ 
Schema support  enabled 


soapSoap Client     enabled 
Soap Server     enabled 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400


socketsSockets Support  enabled 


SPLSPL support  enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject 
Classes     AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilterIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SimpleXMLIterator, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplObjectStorage, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException 


SQLiteSQLite support    enabled
PECL Module version     2.0-dev $Id: sqlite.c,v 1.166.2.13.2.12 2008/12/31 11:17:44 sebastian Exp $ 
SQLite Library  2.8.17 
SQLite Encoding     iso8859 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite.assoc_case   0   0


standardRegex Library   Bundled library enabled 
Dynamic Library Support     enabled 
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars  PHP_    PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars    LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset=    a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset=
user_agent  no value    no value


suhosinThis server is protected with the Suhosin Extension 0.9.31

Copyright (c) 2006-2007 Hardened-PHP Project
Copyright (c) 2007-2010 SektionEins GmbH 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
suhosin.apc_bug_workaround  Off Off
suhosin.cookie.checkraddr   0   0
suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot On  On
suhosin.cookie.cryptkey [ protected ]   [ protected ]
suhosin.cookie.cryptlist    no value    no value
suhosin.cookie.cryptraddr   0   0
suhosin.cookie.cryptua  On  On
suhosin.cookie.disallow_nul 1   1
suhosin.cookie.disallow_ws  1   1
suhosin.cookie.encrypt  Off Off
suhosin.cookie.max_array_depth  50  50
suhosin.cookie.max_array_index_length   64  64
suhosin.cookie.max_name_length  64  64
suhosin.cookie.max_totalname_length 256 256
suhosin.cookie.max_value_length 10000   10000
suhosin.cookie.max_vars 100 100
suhosin.cookie.plainlist    no value    no value
suhosin.coredump    Off Off
suhosin.disable.display_errors  Off Off
suhosin.executor.allow_symlink  Off Off
suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier  Off Off
suhosin.executor.disable_eval   Off Off
suhosin.executor.eval.blacklist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.eval.whitelist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.func.blacklist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.func.whitelist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.include.allow_writable_files   On  On
suhosin.executor.include.blacklist  no value    no value
suhosin.executor.include.max_traversal  0   0
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist  no value    no value
suhosin.executor.max_depth  0   0
suhosin.filter.action   no value    no value
suhosin.get.disallow_nul    1   1
suhosin.get.disallow_ws 0   0
suhosin.get.max_array_depth 50  50
suhosin.get.max_array_index_length  64  64
suhosin.get.max_name_length 64  64
suhosin.get.max_totalname_length    2048    2048
suhosin.get.max_value_length    2048    2048
suhosin.get.max_vars    5000    5000
suhosin.log.file    0   0
suhosin.log.file.name   no value    no value
suhosin.log.phpscript   0   0
suhosin.log.phpscript.is_safe   Off Off
suhosin.log.phpscript.name  no value    no value
suhosin.log.sapi    0   0
suhosin.log.script  0   0
suhosin.log.script.name no value    no value
suhosin.log.syslog  no value    no value
suhosin.log.syslog.facility no value    no value
suhosin.log.syslog.priority no value    no value
suhosin.log.use-x-forwarded-for Off Off
suhosin.mail.protect    0   0
suhosin.memory_limit    0   0
suhosin.mt_srand.ignore On  On
suhosin.multiheader Off Off
suhosin.perdir  0   0
suhosin.post.disallow_nul   1   1
suhosin.post.disallow_ws    0   0
suhosin.post.max_array_depth    50  50
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length 64  64
suhosin.post.max_name_length    64  64
suhosin.post.max_totalname_length   2048    2048
suhosin.post.max_value_length   1000000 1000000
suhosin.post.max_vars   5000    5000
suhosin.protectkey  On  On
suhosin.request.disallow_nul    1   1
suhosin.request.disallow_ws 0   0
suhosin.request.max_array_depth 50  50
suhosin.request.max_array_index_length  64  64
suhosin.request.max_totalname_length    256 256
suhosin.request.max_value_length    1000000 1000000
suhosin.request.max_varname_length  64  64
suhosin.request.max_vars    5000    5000
suhosin.server.encode   On  On
suhosin.server.strip    On  On
suhosin.session.checkraddr  0   0
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot    On  On
suhosin.session.cryptkey    [ protected ]   [ protected ]
suhosin.session.cryptraddr  0   0
suhosin.session.cryptua Off Off
suhosin.session.encrypt On  On
suhosin.session.max_id_length   128 128
suhosin.simulation  Off Off
suhosin.sql.bailout_on_error    Off Off
suhosin.sql.comment 0   0
suhosin.sql.multiselect 0   0
suhosin.sql.opencomment 0   0
suhosin.sql.union   0   0
suhosin.sql.user_postfix    no value    no value
suhosin.sql.user_prefix no value    no value
suhosin.srand.ignore    On  On
suhosin.stealth On  On
suhosin.upload.disallow_binary  0   0
suhosin.upload.disallow_elf 1   1
suhosin.upload.max_uploads  25  25
suhosin.upload.remove_binary    0   0
suhosin.upload.verification_script  no value    no value


tidyTidy support    enabled
libTidy Release     6 November 2007 
Extension Version   2.0 ($Id: tidy.c,v 1.66.2.8.2.26 2008/12/31 11:17:46 sebastian Exp $) 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
tidy.clean_output   0   0
tidy.default_config no value    no value


tokenizerTokenizer Support  enabled 


wddxWDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer     enabled 


xmlXML Support  active 
XML Namespace Support   active 
EXPAT Version   expat_1.95.8 


xmlreaderXMLReader  enabled 


xmlrpccore library version  xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51 
php extension version   0.51 
author  Dan Libby 
homepage    http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net 
open sourced by     Epinions.com 


xmlwriterXMLWriter  enabled 


xslXSL  enabled 
libxslt Version     1.1.26 
libxslt compiled against libxml Version     2.7.6 
EXSLT   enabled 
libexslt Version    1.1.26 


Zend OptimizerOptimization Pass 1   enabled 
Optimization Pass 2     enabled 
Optimization Pass 3     enabled 
Optimization Pass 4     enabled 
Optimization Pass 9     enabled 
Zend Loader     enabled 
License Path    no value 
Obfuscation level   3 


zipZip  enabled 
Extension Version   $Id: php_zip.c,v 1.1.2.49 2009/02/05 19:53:22 pajoye Exp $ 
Zip version     1.8.11 
Libzip version  0.9.0 


zlibZLib Support    enabled 
Stream Wrapper support  compress.zlib:// 
Stream Filter support   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate 
Compiled Version    1.2.3 
Linked Version  1.2.3 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value


Additional ModulesModule Name
ionCube Loader


EnvironmentVariable Value
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1 
HTTP_ACCEPT     text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1 
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET     iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1 
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0 
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-IN,en;q=0.9 
HTTP_CONNECTION     Keep-Alive 
HTTP_HOST   xxxxxxxx.com 
HTTP_USER_AGENT     Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.60 
PATH    /bin:/usr/bin 
QUERY_STRING    no value 
REDIRECT_STATUS     200 
REMOTE_ADDR     114.69.254.2 
REMOTE_PORT     31201 
REQUEST_METHOD  GET 
REQUEST_URI     /test.php 
SCRIPT_FILENAME     /home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.com/test.php 
SCRIPT_NAME     /test.php 
SERVER_ADDR     111.111.111.111 
SERVER_ADMIN    webmaster@xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com 
SERVER_NAME     xxxxxxxx.com 
SERVER_PORT     80 
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.1 
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at xxxxxxxx.com Port 80</address> 
SERVER_SOFTWARE     Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 
UNIQUE_ID   TGYaGNArY6IAAG2MSQwAAAAe 
W3TC_ENC    .gzip 


PHP VariablesVariable   Value
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.com
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"]  iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-IN,en;q=0.9
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  Keep-Alive
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    xxxxxxxx.com
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.60
_SERVER["PATH"] /bin:/usr/bin
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]  200
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  114.69.254.2
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  31201
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /test.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.com/test.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /test.php
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  111.111.111.111
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] webmaster@xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  xxxxxxxx.com
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at xxxxxxxx.com Port 80</address> 
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
_SERVER["UNIQUE_ID"]    TGYaGNArY6IAAG2MSQwAAAAe
_SERVER["W3TC_ENC"] .gzip
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /test.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1281759768
_SERVER["argv"] Array
(
)
_SERVER["argc"] 0
_ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]   /home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.com
_ENV["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]   CGI/1.1
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT"] text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"] iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]    deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]    en-IN,en;q=0.9
_ENV["HTTP_CONNECTION"] Keep-Alive
_ENV["HTTP_HOST"]   xxxxxxxx.com
_ENV["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.60
_ENV["PATH"]    /bin:/usr/bin
_ENV["QUERY_STRING"]    no value
_ENV["REDIRECT_STATUS"] 200
_ENV["REMOTE_ADDR"] 111.111.111.112
_ENV["REMOTE_PORT"] 31201
_ENV["REQUEST_METHOD"]  GET
_ENV["REQUEST_URI"] /test.php
_ENV["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] /home/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.com/test.php
_ENV["SCRIPT_NAME"] /test.php
_ENV["SERVER_ADDR"] 111.111.111.111
_ENV["SERVER_ADMIN"]    webmaster@xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com
_ENV["SERVER_NAME"] xxxxxxxx.com
_ENV["SERVER_PORT"] 80
_ENV["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] HTTP/1.1
_ENV["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]    <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at xxxxxxxx.com Port 80</address> 
_ENV["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
_ENV["UNIQUE_ID"]   TGYaGNArY6IAAG2MSQwAAAAe
_ENV["W3TC_ENC"]    .gzip
```

Comment: This output looks strange when viewed as "plain" text. Didn't recognize it as phpinfo() output at first.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether or not you'll be using these extensions.

If you install extensions that you don't need, you are just slowing down your server.

Comment: I am installing it for a friend, and he asked me to install whatever extensions that he might use in his applications. He is planning to install applications such as Content Management System, etc.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your friend needs to have? Ask him.

Comment: To ask the question more simpler: what are the extensions that come with the hosting companies installation? Say you took a shared hosting from GoDaddy, for Windows Server. What do they have installed already? I do not have access to a PHPINFO on a server to look into that, that is why I am asking here for help.

Comment: @john I don't know what GoDaddy has installed either. It's much easier to go and ask their Tech Support or Sales team than us.

Comment: I thought someone with experience in webhosting might be available on StackOverflow. Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

The CMS will dictate what extensions it needs. More than anything else, you need to take a look at the database backends. Will it be needing MySQLi instead of the MySQL PDO?